# Unable to replace [ with {

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I'm trying to replace `[` with `{` in java with following code:

```
String expectedTimeCriteria = "Month Days=" + monthDays.toString().replaceAll("[", "{");
```

but this throws following error:

```
 java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0 [
                                                                               ^
```

Could you please help me understand what went wrong here?

Comment: post you actual string please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()` as `replaceAll()` is used with the Regex and `[` carries a special meaning in the Regex.

`replace()` on the other hand takes a String and performs the same function as that of `replaceAll()`.

Corrected Code Snippet:

```
String expectedTimeCriteria = "Month Days=" + monthDays.toString().replace("[", "{");
```

Alternatively, you can use the escape character as follows:

```
String expectedTimeCriteria = "Month Days=" + monthDays.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "{");
```

Comment: @TDHM Your Welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

`String#replaceAll` does use regex, so you are having a sematic error for the regex syntax in this case. If you do just want to replace all `[` with `{` you could just use the `String#replace` method, which doesn´t use regex and would still replace each occurence of the searched string.

```
monthDays.toString().replace("[", "{");
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.replaceAll()` takes 2 arguments, the regex and the replacement string. When you pass in "[" as the regex, Java tries to compile it as a regular expression and expects to see the closing "]". That's why you are getting

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0 [
```

You need to escape the character "\[" and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ecape the `[` character with `\\[`

```
String expectedTimeCriteria = "Month Days=" + monthDays.toString().replaceAll("\[", "{");
```

Comment: This is incorrect! It won't even compile. It should be `\\[` and not just `\[`.